# .htaccess file set-up on ubuntu 12.10

Tags: php, .htaccess, apache2

as soon as i save these `.htaccess` file on my server i got a error `500 internal server error`, any idea how can i resolve it. the other issue for some reason these `.htaccess` file works on the tutorial i was watching
http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=Aw28-krO7ZM#at=130

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On

   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
<IfModule>
```

Comment: show me please logs of apache

Comment: [Sun Mar 31 15:44:56 2013] [alert] [client 127.0.0.1] /var/www/mvc/.htaccess: Invalid command 'RewriteEngine', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
[Sun Mar 31 15:46:08 2013] [alert] [client 127.0.0.1] /var/www/mvc/.htaccess: Expected </IfModule> before end of configuration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First error:

Module `mod_rewrite` was not enabled in Apache. After you enable it - the error was gone and website start working.

To enable the module edit apache’s `httpd.conf` file and make sure this line is there uncommented:

```
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

after installation `mod_rewrite` on your system.

Second error:

Change last line of `.htaccess` file to:

```
</IfModule>
```

I hope I helped.

Comment: thank you mkjasinski i have change </IfModule> the error is gone!